# mysql- insert 0 for records that don't have a value

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm building an application which will list exam related details of a student.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `es_student` (
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fname` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `es_student` (`student_id`, `fname`) VALUES
(1,'John');
```

There are multiple subjects

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `es_subject` (
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `es_subject` (`subject_id`, `subject`) VALUES
(1,'Math'),
(2,'English'),
(3,'Science'),
(4,'Physics');
```

There is more than one exam. But not all exams have been conducted for a subject.
Eg: For Math, all three exams have been conducted but for English only one was conducted. So, I want to show zero as marks for those exams (for a subject) that have not been conducted.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `es_exam` (
  `exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exam` varchar(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `es_exam` (`exam_id`, `exam`) VALUES
(1,'Exam 1'),
(2,'Exam 2'),
(3,'Exam 3');
```

This is how I store all marks

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `es_mark` (
  `mark_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `exam_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subject_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `student_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mark` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=42 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `es_mark` (`mark_id`, `exam_id`,`subject_id`, `student_id`,`mark`) VALUES
(1,1,1,1,11),
(2,2,1,1,15),
(3,3,1,1,12),
(4,3,2,1,11),
(5,1,3,1,1),
(6,3,3,1,2),
(7,2,4,1,3);
```

But the query I wrote does not show zero for those exams that have not been conducted.

```
SELECT es_mark.mark_id,es_mark.mark,es_exam.exam ,es_subject.subject,es_subject.subject_id,es_student.fname
FROM es_mark
LEFT JOIN es_subject ON es_mark.subject_id=es_subject.subject_id
LEFT JOIN es_student ON es_mark.student_id=es_student.student_id
LEFT JOIN es_exam ON es_exam.exam_id=es_mark.exam_id
WHERE es_mark.student_id=1
GROUP BY es_mark.mark_id
```

This is the result I got:

```
mark_id     mark    exam    subject     subject_id  fname
1            11     Exam 1  Math           1        John
2            15     Exam 2  Math           1        John
3            12     Exam 3  Math           1        John
4            11     Exam 3  English        2        John
5            1      Exam 1  Science        3        John
6            2      Exam 3  Science        3        John
7            3      Exam 2  Physics        4        John
```

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
mark_id     mark    exam    subject     subject_id  fname
1            11     Exam 1  Math         1          John
2            15     Exam 2  Math         1          John
3            12     Exam 3  Math         1          John
4            11     Exam 3  English      2          John
0             0     Exam 2  English      2          John
0             0     Exam 1  English      2          John
```

and so on..

Is it possible to insert zeros as marks for those exams that haven't been conducted?

**[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfcae/2)**

P.S: mark_id is irrelevant. I know it cannot repeat as it's a primary key field and I put 0 in the desired output for that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this query the trick is within the deliverd table with two cross joins.
These cross joins makes 4 * 3 * 1 = 12 records with the data in the tables es_subject,  es_exam and es_student to make all possible combinations between these three tables.

Please note that you cant get the order that you try to achieve thats why mine result is different but the mark_id and mark are zero's where there is no match.

```
SELECT 

   IF (es_mark.mark_id IS NULL, 0, es_mark.mark_id) AS mark_id
 , IF (es_mark.mark IS NULL, 0, es_mark.mark) AS mark
 , all_exam.exam
 , all_exam.subject
 , all_exam.subject_id
 , all_exam.fname 

FROM (
 SELECT 
   *
 FROM 
   es_subject
 CROSS JOIN
   es_exam
 CROSS JOIN 
   es_student 
) 
 AS
  all_exam 

LEFT JOIN
  es_mark
ON 
    all_exam.exam_id = es_mark.exam_id
  AND 
    all_exam.subject_id = es_mark.subject_id

LEFT JOIN 
  es_subject
ON
 es_mark.subject_id = es_subject.subject_id

 LEFT JOIN
  es_student    
 ON
  es_mark.student_id = es_student.student_id   

LEFT JOIN
  es_exam
ON
  es_exam.exam_id = es_mark.exam_id 

ORDER BY 
    all_exam.subject_id ASC
  , all_exam.exam ASC
```

Result

```
mark_id    mark  exam    subject  subject_id  fname   
-------  ------  ------  -------  ----------  --------
      1      11  Exam 1  Math              1  John    
      2      15  Exam 2  Math              1  John    
      3      12  Exam 3  Math              1  John    
      0       0  Exam 1  English           2  John    
      0       0  Exam 2  English           2  John    
      4      11  Exam 3  English           2  John    
      5       1  Exam 1  Science           3  John    
      0       0  Exam 2  Science           3  John    
      6       2  Exam 3  Science           3  John    
      0       0  Exam 1  Physics           4  John    
      7       3  Exam 2  Physics           4  John    
      0       0  Exam 3  Physics           4  John
```

see demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bfcae/6

Answer (score 0):

```
`mark` int(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the result using sql query? @kingtut007

Comment: Even if I set it as default 0; it won't fetch the result the way i mentioned. @kingtut007

Comment: you could do an update statement and add 0 to the empty ones. and then modify the table structure to accept default 0. Or you could just be like select mark_id,case mark when null then 0 END as mark,exam,subject,subject_id,fname from es_mark

Comment: Tried case but not expected result. @kingtut007

Comment: Same result as I got in the fiddle. @kingtut007

Comment: Your table should have a flag to show that the exam was conducted or not.

Answer (score 0):

use should have to use DEFAULT value.
The default value will be added to all new records, if no other value is specified.

Comment: I did. but it won't fetch it. Check the sql fiddle I added. @Prashant Kumar Singh

Comment: how you got 0 values for marks ?in above query you insert 1,2,3 for last 3 marks then how it give default value?@SajeevC

Comment: I didn't get zero. for english only exam3 was conducted . so for exam1 and exam2, I'm trying to show zeros @Prashant Kumar Singh

Answer (score 0):

You will need to adjust `mark` to the following:

```
`mark` int(11) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL
```

From what your example showed, it was pulling and adding data into the `mark` field with 1,2 & 3. As such it was not defaulting to 0 since there was data being supplied into it.

For INSERT queries, they must have all fields populated as it won't allow an empty field of data even if you declare a column with a DEFAULT value. You would need to have separate INSERT INTO queries for one with and without the `mark` data populated. Example below -

```
INSERT INTO `es_mark` (`mark_id`, `exam_id`,`subject_id`, `student_id`,`mark`) VALUES
(1,1,1,1,11),
(2,2,1,1,15),
(3,3,1,1,12),
(4,3,2,1,11);
INSERT INTO `es_mark` (`mark_id`, `exam_id`,`subject_id`, `student_id`)
VALUES
(5,2,2,1),
(6,1,2,1);
```

Hopefully this helps you get on the right track for what you're wanting to accomplish with your project.